# Invoking routes for mocha test

Tags: node.js, express, routes, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to write unit testing using mocha and chai, the major problem i am facing across is that for each API i have to specifically define the url, i.e.

**test.js**

```
var expect = require('chai').expect;
var should = require('chai').should;
var express = require('express');
var chai = require('chai');
var chaiHttp = require('chai-http');
chai.use(chaiHttp);

var baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/api';

describe("Test case for getting all the  users", function(){
                it("Running test", function(done){

                    this.timeout(10000);    //to check if the API is taking too much time to return the response.

                    var url = baseUrl + '/v1/users?access_token=fd085c73227b94fb3d1d5552b5a62be963b6d068'

                    chai.request(url)
                    .get('')
                    .end(function(err, res) {
                        //console.log('routes>>>>', routes);
                        expect(err).to.be.null;
                        expect(res.statusCode).to.equal(200);   // <= Call done to signal callback end
                            expect(res).to.have.property('text');
                            done();                              
                    });
                });
            });
```

I want that all my routes should directly get invoke from my **routes.js** file instead of hard coding each and every url, **is it possible**?
TIA.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an init function for a router object to fill your routes. Use that init function both for tests and actual code. Here is an example:

```
//
// initRouter.js
//
function initRouter(router){
    router.route('/posts')
        .post(function(req, res) {
            console.log('req.body:', req.body)
            //Api code
        });
    router.route('/posts/:post_id')
        .get(function(req, res) {
            console.log('req.body:', req.body)
            //Api code
        })
    return router;
}
module.exports = initRouter;

//
// in the consumer code
//
var initer = require('./initRouter');
app.use('/api', initer(express.Router()));
```

Answer (score 0):

In the example you are presenting you are testing an existing Web server exposed through some IP and PORT. Using [express-mocks-http](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-mocks-http) you can mock express request and response objects and pass those directly to the route function you define. See the package documentation for more information.

Comment: Thanks, i will give it a try.